# How to export coldfusion site to word with button event

Tags: coldfusion

so I know by using these headers at the top:

```
<cfcontent type="application/msword; cht=utf-8">
<cfheader name="Content-Type" value="application/msword">
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;
filename=Staff-List.doc">
```

the site opens in a word document, but I want to have the site open normally and then if I click a button, for example "donwload as word" then it downloads, but I can't find anywhere the syntax to do even something similar, how could I do it?

This is what I've tried so far

```
     <cfif isDefined("url.submit_docs")>
     <cfcontent type="application/msword; cht=utf-8">
     <cfheader name="Content-Type" value="application/msword">
     <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;
      filename=Staff-List.doc"></cfif>
```

I have the information withing a form, and when I click the "download as word" button which name is "submit_docs" I get a browser error indicating it cannot locate the file.

The form looks something like this:

```
       <form >
    <div id="MainWrapper"  >
    <cfoutput>
    my info
    </cfoutput>
     <input type= 'submit'  value= 'Download as MS word' name="submit_docs">
    </form>
```

Comment: Please show the code you describe in the last sentence, and the error you get.

Comment: You need to put the content to be downloaded before the attachment disposition

Answer (score 2):

This might be silly, but based on your code this line:

```
 <cfif isDefined("url.submit_docs")>
```

Should be referencing a FORM element as in:

```
 <cfif isDefined("FORM.submit_docs")>
```

Your submit button is inside a form correct?

There is also a "file" attribute to the  tag... so you can do this:

```
<cfcontent type="application/msword; cht=utf-8" file="filename=Staff-List.doc">
```

I usually add headers as well, but I'm not sure they are needed.